# Is there some way to handle an input when it is being disabing / enabling in Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events, jquery-events

Today I made some screens in the software I develop, and I need detect when an input is being disabled and enabled to show/hide another element.
I know how to do it by bind the checkbox which enables and disables my input, but I want to know whether there is a way to handle the input instead of checkbox.

Thanks

Comment: use $(input).attr("enabled")...It will return true or false

Comment: @Hammad 1) there is no enabled attribute  - perhaps you mean `$( "input:enabled" )` which is a collection 2) that will not detect WHEN it is disabled/enabled

Comment: @GregBurghardt no answer in that link covers the disabling/enabling

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes it does. The `propertychange` event in jQuery covers this.

Comment: Hi guys. I saw that link and setInterval is not an option to me. The software follows a design pattern and I can't use it. Our software is compatible with IE9+ and I think propertychanged event will not fire.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I do not see that work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qngaqjkL/

Comment: I found a way. I need to learn more about it, but it's a way. Using javascript MutationObserver object I got the expected result. But it is only compatible with IE11+

More information about this object here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit